# how to calculate days between two dates monthwise in javascript

Tags: javascript, calendar, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I'm stuck in a problem that is, I want to calculate number of days between two selected dates from bootstrap `daterangepicker` month wise, i.e.
let us assume that

```
start date = 07/19/2018 
end date  = 09/28/2018
```

The result should be:

```
number of days in 07 = 13 days
number of days in 08 = 31 days
number of days in 09 = 28 days
total number of days = 72 days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In simple way... (but slow)**

```js
var date1 = new Date('07/19/2018'),
    date2 = new Date('09/28/2018'),
    tmp_date;
if (date1 > date2) {
    tmp_date = date1;
    date1 = date2;
    date2 = tmp_date;
}

var tmp_date = date1,
    out_date = new Date(+date2 + 86400000),
    date_map = {}, year, month, date, total_days = 0;
while (+tmp_date < +out_date) {
    year = tmp_date.getFullYear();
    month = tmp_date.getMonth() + 1;
    date = tmp_date.getDate();
    if (!date_map[year]) {
        date_map[year] = {};
    }
    if (!date_map[year][month]) {
        date_map[year][month] = 1;
    } else {
        ++date_map[year][month];
    }
    tmp_date = new Date(+tmp_date + 86400000);
    ++total_days;
}

for (var year in date_map) {
    for (var month in date_map[year]) {
        console.log('number of days in ' + year + '/' + month + ' = ' + date_map[year][month] + ' days');
    }
}
console.log('total number of days = ' + total_days + ' days');

console.log(date_map);
console.log(total_days);
```

Comment: thanks @Jason for your answer it's really useful and helped me, you only able to understand my question and answered. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

@Jason beats me to it, but here is my shorter version.

```js
let start = new Date("07/19/2018");
let end = new Date("09/28/2018");
let div = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth() + 1, 1);
while (end.getFullYear() !== start.getFullYear() || end.getMonth() !== start.getMonth()) {
 console.log((div.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
 start = new Date(div.getTime());
 div.setMonth(div.getMonth() + 1);
}
console.log((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

add 1 to the end for inclusive.

Comment: Good answer, shorter and faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just diff and convert to day.

`(new Date("09/28/2018").getTime() - new Date("07/19/2018").getTime())/(24*60*60*1000) + 1`

Comment: this is not the solution what I want @Rick , kindly read the question carefully I want to get the number of days for each month separately in a daterange

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total number of days using the following code.

```js
let str = new Date("07/19/2018");
let end = new Date("09/28/2018");
let totalDays = (end.getTime() - str.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

To get the number of days month wise, you will have to get the date, month, and year as separate inputs and count the number of days by incrementally increasing the month by 1 each time until the date does not exceed the end date.